# how do you wrap images around a main image?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, layout

I have an idea of how to do it. I just cannot figure out how to get it to work. I am well aware that i need to update the mysql. I'll do that in at a later time. I cannot figure out how to get the photos to tile under the main image.

This is the page code.

```
<?php
//$_GET['hideHeader'] = 1;
include "sql.php";



$car_id = intval($_GET['id']);
$x = mysql_query("select * from cars where id=" . $car_id);

$car = mysql_fetch_array($x, MYSQL_ASSOC);
if (!$car) die("This vehicle no longer exists.");

$title = (intval($car['year']) > 0 ? $car['year'] . " " : "") . $car['make'] . " " . $car['model'] . " " . $car['category'] . " at Morabito Motors";
$showSide = false;
include "header.php";
include "carpreview.php";

?><body id="box">



<div>
    <?php showCarPreview($car); ?>
</div>

<div style="float: right; margin: 0px 0px 20px 10px; width: 105px; overflow: auto;">

<?php

$x = mysql_query("select id,main from images where car_id=" . $car_id . " order by main desc,id desc");
while ($y = mysql_fetch_array($x, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    if (!isset($img)) $img = $y;
    ?>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <!-- a href="viewpic.php?car_id=<?=$car_id?>&img_id=<?=$y['id']?>" -->
        <img src="/images/vehicles/<?=$car_id?>-<?=$y['id']?>t.jpg" onMouseOver="javascript:showImage(<?=$y['id']?>);">
        <!-- /a -->

    </div>
    <?php
}

?>

</div>

<?php

if (isset($img))
{
    ?>
    <img id="fullsize" src="images/vehicles/<?=$car_id?>-<?=$img['id']?>.jpg" width=640>
    <?php
}

?>

<script language="javascript">
function showImage(id)
{
    document.getElementById("fullsize").src = "images/vehicles/<?=$car_id?>-" + id + ".jpg";
}
</script>

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

It looks like this now.
[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/a9lwwh)

Comment: I can't edit my type o i meant to type image, not inage.

Comment: When you say 'around' do you mean you want a large image in the center with a number of thumbnails wrapping it around all sides (i.e. top, right, bottom, left)?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i mean samurai_jane

Comment: Are you taking responsive design into account or are you only designing for desktop?

Comment: If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it.